# Using REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract website domain

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field called Website with examples that look like:

```
https://ivalore.com.br
https://cornstalk.com
https://penny.co
```

I am trying to use REGEXP_SUBSTR to isolate the domain:
`REGEXP_SUBSTR("Website", '[^https://]+')`

Some of the results are working but others are not, for instance I am expecting cornstalk.com and penny.co but I am not receiving those values:

```
ivalore.com.br
corn
enny.co
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not a simple `replace(col,'https://','')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("Website", '^(https?://)?(.*)', 1, 1, 'e', 2)
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(https?://)?` - an optional Group 1: `http://` or `https://`
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the string.

The last argument, together with `e` last but one argument, returns the Group 2 value.

However, `REGEXP_REPLACE` might be better here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("Website", '^https?://', '')
```

That is, just remove the `http://` or `https://` from the start of a string.

Comment: Thank for this. Confirming that the REGEXP_SUBSTR worked and great point about the REGEXP_REPLACE. Also appreciate you breaking things down as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using built-in [PARSE_URL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_url.html):

> Returns a JSON object consisting of all the components (fragment, **host**, path, port, query, scheme) in a valid input URL/URI.

```
WITH cte(url) AS (
  SELECT 'https://ivalore.com.br' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://cornstalk.com' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'https://penny.co'
)
SELECT url, PARSE_URL(url):"host"::TEXT AS host
FROM cte;
```

Output:

[image]